# How to use BulkProcessor in version 8 +

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm upgrading from elasticsearch 7 client to 8 and trying to stop using the deprecated RestHighLevelClient. The issue is that in one of the modules i am having BulkProcessor, and i can't figure out how I can use it with the new clients library, since none of them is compatible.

```java
public static Builder builder(Client client, Listener listener, Scheduler flushScheduler, Scheduler retryScheduler, Runnable onClose) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(client, "client");
    Objects.requireNonNull(listener, "listener");
    return new Builder(client::bulk, listener, flushScheduler, retryScheduler, onClose);
}
```

The builder above expects package `org.elasticsearch.client.internal.Client` and i don't find any implementation i can use in any of the dependencies below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Am i missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: May be you can get some idea from [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessorTests.java) as documentation is not fully complete yet.

Comment: There is no equivalent yet in the new java client, see [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/108#issuecomment-1012996196). Maybe you have to change your approach using bulkrequest.